# CkEditor5 - Making div inside UIElement as contenteditable is not working

Tags: ckeditor, contenteditable, ckeditor5

I have a UIElement inside editor (hosted using Ckeditor5). UiElement contains buttons and a div say 'xyz'. I have added  "data-cke-ignore-events"  to be true to the UIElement. I wanted this div 'xyz' to be contenteditable and I added contenteditable attribute. But it doesn't work. If I click on the div, focus is going back to editor content. Not able to click and have caret inside the div within the UIElement.

Tried adding the attribute  "data-cke-ignore-events"  to div 'xyz' as well. But it is not working.